# Tracker GET request parameters in Bittorrent

Tags: protocols, bittorrent

When using Bittorrent, I saw there are the parameters "`numwant`", "`corrupt`" and "`key`" in URL.

However, I found these paremeters don't be defined in BEP 3 (http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html), so could someone tell me the meaning of the parameters, and where are the 3 parameters defined?

Also, before asking the questsion, I had searched the keyword "`numwant`" in the site www.bittorrent.org, and just found "`numwant`" appears in BEP 8, but the definition or explanation of the keyword can't be found.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While BEP3 is official, it's a terse and dense document. I would instead recommend you to use the inofficial: https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification

It's a lot easier to read and understand. It also document some early extensions to the protocol that you can't find elsewhere.

There you will find:

> - **numwant**: Optional. Number of peers that the client would like to receive from the tracker. This value is permitted to be zero. If omitted, typically defaults to 50 peers.
> - **key**: Optional. An additional identification that is not shared with any other peers. It is intended to allow a client to prove their identity should their IP address change.

Regarding `corrupt`, there is afaik no written documentation how it is defined, but it's rather simple; When a piece fails the hash check, that amount of data is accounted on the `corrupt` counter instead of the `downloaded` counter.

There is also a similar `redundant` counter, where data that is discharged because it's redundant is acconuted. This happens, for example, in *end game mode*, when the same chunk is requested from more than one peer.

---

Also, there is some additional info in my answer here: [Understanding Bittorrent Tracker Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194433/understanding-bittorrent-tracker-request/44197266#44197266)